# Timeout for ExecutorService without blocking the main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I would like to execute some work in a background with a time limit. The thing is, I don't want to block the main thread.

Naive implementation is to have two executor services. One for scheduling/timeout and the second one will be responsible for getting work done.

```
final ExecutorService backgroundExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
final ExecutorService workerExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadExecutor();


backgroundExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Future future = workerExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // do work
            }
        });
        try {
            future.get(120 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("InterruptedException while notifyTransactionStateChangeListeners()", e);
            future.cancel(true);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            logger.error("ExecutionException", e);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            logger.error("TimeoutException", e);
            future.cancel(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: One simplification would be a single 2 thread pool with one thread doing the job and the other waiting for it.  That at least saves the inner pool but otherwise is not much help.

Comment: Is it possible to issue the tasks to both Timer and Executor at the same time?  One will get into run() first and so a lock or synchronize would be needed somewhere to arbitrate between timed out and task completed so that the correct action could be taken in each case.  Hmm.. not sure.

Comment: Since you ignore the result of Future.get() in your code, I wonder whether you really need to wait for the result in some thread?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an ExecutorService just to run a single thread one time like that. You can create a FutureTask instead which gives you the same benefits without the overhead.

```
FutureTask<T> future = new FutureTask<T>(callable);
Thread thread = new Thread(future);
thread.start();
try {
    future.get(120 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} ...
```

The callable in the above snippet would be your task.
If you have a Runnable (as you do in your above code block) you can turn it into a Callable via:

```
Callable callable = Executors.callable(runnable, null);
```

So, to summarize, your code could change to:

```
backgroundExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // do work
            }
        } 

        Callable callable = Executors.callable(myRunnable, null);

        FutureTask<T> future = new FutureTask<T>(callable);
        Thread thread = new Thread(future);
        thread.start();

        try {
            future.get(120 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("InterruptedException while notifyTransactionStateChangeListeners()", e);
            future.cancel(true);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            logger.error("ExecutionException", e);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            logger.error("TimeoutException", e);
            future.cancel(true);
        } 
    }
});
```

You don't need a finally to shut down the executor. Though you might still want a finally to clean up any other resources.

Comment: future.get is a blocking operation. OP asked how to do it in an unblocking way.

Comment: @codemania23: The blocking logic is inside of a second runnable. As long as `outFuture.get()` isn't called this is not blocking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Executor Service along with CompletableFuture. CompletableFuture runAsync accepts Runnable and ExecutorService Arguments.

```
final ExecutorService workerExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadExecutor();

void queueTask(TaskId taskId) {
        workerExecutor.submit(() -> processTaskAsync(taskId));
    }

private void processTaskAsync(TaskId taskId) {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> processTask(taskId), this.workerExecutor)
                .whenComplete((ok, error) -> {
                    if (error != null) {
                        log.error("Exception while processing task", error);
                    } else {
                        log.info("finished post processing for task id {}", taskId.getValue());
                    }
                });
}
```