# ExecutorService - How to wait for completition of all tasks in non-blocking style

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, executorservice

I am using `ExecutorService` in **Java web server application** for executing some computational tasks in parallel style and then calling `shutdown()` with `awaitTermination()` to wait for all tasks to be done. Whole computation can sometimes take dozens of minutes.

The thing is `awaitTermination()` method blocks the main thread until timeout elapsed (or *interrupted*) but I just want to start the tasks and **immediatedly respond** to client and after competition of all tasks shutdown the service (*following conventions to always close the thread pool*).

So my question, is there a way how I can **be notified when all tasks are done** so I could call the `shutdown()` method? Listener or something..

Thanks!

Comment: Call awaitTermination() in a new Thread?

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate of the following question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826212/java-executors-how-to-be-notified-without-blocking-when-a-task-completes

Comment: or this one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333895/timeout-for-executorservice-without-blocking-the-main-thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333895/timeout-for-executorservice-without-blocking-the-main-thread)

Comment: @VGR Could you please be more detailed? I don't see what you mean.

Comment: @thisismyusername I saw that question, but it is a different situation. I don't want to chain the tasks so when one completes, execute another. I just want to run all tasks at once.

Comment: @Supermartzin Create a Runnable whose `run()` method calls awaitTermination().  Pass that Runnable to `new Thread` and call that Thread's start() method.

Comment: @VGR I see what you mean, so basically I create another single `Thread` in which I wrap my existing code. I'll try it, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to solve a problem that doesn’t exist. Consider the [documentation of `ExecutorService.shutdown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--):

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. …
>
> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution.

In other words, just calling `shutdown()` does already everything you want

- It finishes all previously submitted tasks
- It initiates a shutdown
- It does not wait

The only obstacle is that you are calling `awaitTermination` despite the fact that you don’t want to wait, which has a trivial solution: *don’t call* `awaitTermination`.

The confusion arises because in your question you are asking “how I can be notified when all tasks are done so I could call the `shutdown()` method” but that is in contradiction to what you are actually doing in the code. You are calling `awaitTermination` **after** `shutDown` so you are not waiting in order to initiate the shutdown, but initiating the `shutdown` first and waiting for its completion then, which is the purpose of `awaitTermination`, waiting for the *completion of the shutdown*.

---

To put it in one sentence, just call `shutDown` after submission in order to shutdown the service after completion of all submitted jobs and don’t call `awaitTermination` unless you really want to wait for the termination.

Comment: Thanks, I got confused by this sentence in API documentation: `This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution.` I assumed that all submitted and non-completed tasks will be terminated before execution but now I see that by only calling `shutdown()` I get desired behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: I still have one more question: Is there a way how to find out when the execution queue gets empty, when last task execution ends?

Comment: That are two different things. The queue holds the jobs which haven’t started execution yet (you could check with `getQueue().isEmpty()`). But an empty queue does not imply that there aren’t some jobs still running. You may check `getActiveCount()` but keep in mind, that’s an estimate. Having all jobs done is what `awaitTermination` implies, finishing of all jobs (plus termination of the threads). If you want to wait for the service to become idle, without terminating it, I’m afraid that that hasn’t been foreseen by the standard `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comment from [VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) I solved my problem with creating yet another `Thread` in which I wrapped my existing code like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    collection.forEach(item -> service.submit(() -> {
            // some computational work
        });

    try {
        service.shutdown()
        service.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    catch (InterruptedException iEx) {
        // handle exception
    }
});

thread.start();

return ResponseToClient();
```

Comment: this does not make any sence, see @Holger explanation

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I think he didn't put his question properly, he actually messed himself in awaitTermination(). His requirement was to start the tasks asynchronously and shutdown the ExecutorService once all tasks are finished. So, running his ExecutorService in new thread worked for him, and he never needed awaitTermination() as correctly explained by Holger.

Comment: @hagrawal it can be done in main thread without awaitTermination() call - tasks will run asynchronously and service will be shut down at the end.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Yes, I agree, that's why I said that he messed up with awaitTermination(), he simply needed async behavior and shutdown() was already doing its job well.

Comment: @hagrawal Yes, you are right guys, I got confused with one sentence in API documentation, thanks for help anyway.

Comment: @Supermartzin No problem, we are all here to learn, help and get helped. :)